# MATLAB re-position colorbar title

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, 4d

I would like to reposition the colorbar title (not the colorbar itself). I tried using the following code:

```
cb = colorbar;                                    
set(get(cb,'title'),'string','Dislocation Density(m^{-2})'); 

lbpos = get(cb,'title');
pos = get (lbpos,'position'); 
set(lbpos, 'position', pos) ;
```

I have got three problems:

- there are four numbers in the vector `pos` and I don't know which number should I modified in order to move the title upward so that it would not overlap the colorbar.
- I have tried to alter some number in `pos` but whatever I do the title just move down and overlap with the colorbar.
- In addition, when I try to enlarge the whole graph with the <kbd>maximize</kbd> button at the upper right corner, the position of the colorbar title also changes. This doesn't happen if I don't try to re-position the colorbar title.

Comment: generally `pos` is defined as `[startH startW lengthH lengthW]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation on [text object](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html#input_argument_namevalue_position), the `'Position'` of a text object only has 3 numbers [x,y,z] when the `'Units'` is `data`, which is also the default setting. So I think your colorbar text is somehow modified. Let's try this:

```
cb = colorbar;                                    
set(get(cb,'title'),'string','Dislocation Density(m^{-2})'); 
lbpos = get(cb,'title');

% change Units to data
set(lbpos,'Units','data');
% get position, should have 2 or 3 values
pos = get (lbpos,'position'); 
% move up a bit
pos(2) = pos(2)+3;
set(lbpos, 'position', pos);
```

Comment: I have tried your method, but even I use pos(2)+300 the colorbar title doesn't move at all. Which number of the vector "pos" represent the position of the colorbar title?

Comment: Have you changed the Units to data ? According to the [documentation](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html#input_argument_namevalue_position), the vector 'position' is [x,y] or [x,y,z], so all number define the position of the colorbar title (**'Units'** is **data**). If so try set(lbpos, 'position', pos(1:2)); as vector of 2 should work. I think setting pos with a vector of 4 causes your problem

Comment: I tried to use the following:
cb = colorbar;                                  
set(get(cb,'title'),'string','Dislocation Density(m^{-2})'); 
lbpos = get(cb,'title');
set(lbpos,'Units','data');
pos = get (lbpos,'position'); 
pos(2) = pos(2)-50;
set(lbpos, 'position', pos(1:2));
But it still doesn't work. The MATLAB version I use is 2014a.

Comment: hmm I run your script and it works.  See [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/H17ME.png). I use Matlab r2013a

Comment: Try this one: `set(lbpos,'units','normalized','position',[0,1.03]);` . It works for me as well

Comment: Or maybe try this one too: `set(lbpos,'Parent',cb);`. My advise is too run `get(lbpos)` before and after modifying anything to see if anything went wrong

Comment: The command: : set(lbpos,'units','normalized','position',[0,1.03]); works for me. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know why other commands cannot work. In addition, even I use set(lbpos,'units','normalized','position',[0,1.03]); the space between the colorbar and its title changes when I maximize the figure's dialogue. Which one is the "correct" figure, the maximized or non-maximized?

Comment: In general, the Units `normalized` means it is normalized to the parent container. So i think it's normal to observe some changes in the distance when you maximize the figure, although it is not that clear to me (maybe because I have small laptop screen). If you wish, you can look at the [documentation](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html#input_argument_namevalue_position) and play around with different setting of `Units` and `Position`